# Rails upvote/downvote using Ajax with acts_as_votable

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

Still fairly new to Rails. I used the acts_as_votable gem to create upvote and upvote buttons to allow users to upvote/downvote videos, but I can't make them change from upvote / downvote (and vice versa) and update the counter each time they click without refreshing the page. I tried following other kind-of-similar answers without luck.  Here's what I tried to implement.

index.html.erb

```
<% @videos.each do |x| %>
<p> <div class="child">  
  <video controls width="310" height="230" src="<%= x.file %>"></video>
        <div class="btn-group">
            <%= link_to upvote_video_path(x), method: :put, remote: :true, id: "like-count", class: "btn btn-default btn-sm" do %>
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-up"></span>
            Upvote
           <div id="video-<% x.id %>"> <%= x.get_upvotes.size %> </div>
            <% end %>
            <% end %>
          </div>
          </div>

 <%= x.title %> 

</div> </p>
<% end %>
```

upvote.js.erb (located in the videos view folder)

```
$("#video-<%= x.id %>").html('<%= x.get_upvotes.size %>');
```

def upvote

```
    @video = Video.find(params[:id])
    @ip = request.remote_ip
    was_it_upvoted = Ipaddresstracker.find_by(ipaddress: @ip, videoid:   @video.id)
    if was_it_upvoted
      @video.downvote_by User.first
      was_it_upvoted.delete
    else
      Ipaddresstracker.create(:ipaddress => @ip, :videoid => @video.id)
      @video.vote_by voter: User.first, :duplicate => true
    end
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_back fallback_location: root_path }
      format.json { render layout:false }
  end
```

Routes

```
resources :videos do#, only: [:index, :show] do
  member do
    put "upvote", to: "videos#upvote"
    put "downvote", to: "videos#downvote"
  end
end
```

application.js

```
//= require introjs
//=require rails-ujs
//= require turbolinks
//= require_tree .
```

application.html.erb (head tag)

```
<head>
  <title>Workspace</title>
    <%= csrf_meta_tags %>

    <%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
    <%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>

    <link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.2/css/bootstrap-combined.min.css" rel="stylesheet" id="bootstrap-css">
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
</head>
```

Comment: Where do you handle your `ajax:success` event?

Comment: I'm not sure I follow what that means.

Comment: Your `link_to upvote_video_path(x)` has `remote: :true` (should be `remote: true`). Which means that the link is submitting using UJS (ajax). Which also means that you'll have an `ajax:success` event that occurs upon successful click of your link. You can read more about it [here](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/working_with_javascript_in_rails.html#link-to). Without an `ajax:success` handler, your page isn't going to do anything when you click on the link - which is what's happening now.

Comment: That makes a lot of sense.  I added a class to the button `<div class="btn-group upvotingthis">`, and this is the new up vote.js.erb. `$( ".upvotingthis" ).on( "click", function() {
  $("#video-<%= x.id %>").html('<%= x.get_upvotes.size %>');
});`. I think I'm still missing something, because the page doesn't reload but all the elements do if I click on just one of them.  Edit:  Just tried replacing the html with a simple string, still not going through.  Might be because of x.id and I'm not using an instance variable in place of x.  Going to investigate.

Comment: @ChrisWilson in your template snippet you forgot the `=` to display the id here: `<div id="video-<% x.id %>">`. It should be `video-<%= x.id %>`. Is it a typo ?

Comment: Yeah my bad, that was a typo just on the stack overflow.